# How to move edittext above keyboard when click in relativelayout

Tags: android, android-edittext

in my .xml
the last editext(@id/add_link_Text) is covered by keyboard

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
  android:background="@drawable/background"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context=".RemindMeInsertEvent" >

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:text="@string/add_event"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/add_event_Text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
    android:hint="@string/event_name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" >

    <requestFocus android:layout_width="match_parent" />

  </EditText>

  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/add_location_Text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/add_event_Text"
    android:hint="@string/event_location" />

  <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/dropdown_month"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/add_location_Text"
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
    android:entries="@array/months"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

  <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/dropdown_day"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/add_location_Text"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/dropdown_month"
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
    android:entries="@array/days"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

  <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dip"
    android:layout_below="@id/dropdown_day" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Event Description"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

</ScrollView>

  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/add_link_Text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/ScrollView01"
    android:hint="@string/link" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button_add_events"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/add_link_Text"
    android:text="@string/save" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and in my manifest:

```
   <activity
        android:name="com.example.feastdiriwangv2.remindme.RemindMeInsertEvent"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_remind_me_insert_event"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan" >
    </activity>
```

I don't know whats wrong with it., im just following some of answered questions here in stackoveflow but it seems like its not working on me.

Comment: put this in the activity in the manifest `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|keyboard`

Comment: change adjustPan to adjustResize. This will cause the layout to resize, when the keyboard shows up. Not sure if that is what you want, but it sounds like it

Comment: Thank you El_Mochiq and  peshkira.., the code is working now.,
I had tried what you said, I just found that all i need to dot is to delete the old one of my app before installing the new one.,

Comment: not working for me in a Fragment as a child of a FragmentActivity.